# Can Objective-C subclass without calling init

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I'm using a third party library that doesn't not expose its init method and does some specialized I-don't-know-what from class-level message. Does that prohibit me from subclassing?

I made a test case (ARC enabled)

A.h

```
@interface A : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * bar;
-(id) initWithAbar:(NSString *) bar;
+(id) aWithBar:(NSString *) bar;
@end
```

A.m

```
#import "A.h"
@implementation A
-(id) initWithAbar:(NSString *) bar
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.bar = bar;
    }
    return self;
}


+(id) aWithBar:(NSString *) bar
{
    return [[A alloc] initWithAbar:bar];
}

@end
```

B.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "A.h"

@interface B : A
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *foo;
-(id) initWithFoo:(NSString *)foo bar:(NSString *)bar;
@end
```

B.m

```
#import "B.h"

@implementation B

-(id) initWithFoo:(NSString *)foo bar:(NSString *)bar
{
    self = (B*)[A aWithBar:bar]; // Still actually A, knew that by printing [self class];
    if (self) {
        self.foo = foo; // Error: unrecognized selector here
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Suppose I cannot just call A's `initWithAbar:`, any choice I have in subclassing A? What's so special about init anyway if A's aWithBar is calling A's init?

Comment: I upvoted this months ago, but by that time I didn't have any question. But now stumbling on it again I am curious. Did you manage to solve this? Did the answer below work for you? If you could be so kind as to share your result, it would be very nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't try the class-dump solution. I couldn't get the first nor the third solution to work, either. It is possibly due to the original library developer "not being careful". Eventually I opted for composition instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Funny thing about that line is "not being careful" seems to sound "good" here. It needs deciphering. Am I correct? Other words, if he override `init` and called `self` it would be doable, if not, undoable? Would you mind sharing the composite version? Is it something like having class `C` in which class `A` (from the framework) and class `B` combined? Have a good one.

Comment: Composition simply means having class A object as a class B object's member variable and I simply forward messages to B to A. Of course that means Class B is not a subclass of A anymore. That may break code which rely on the inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes:

- `- [NSObject init]` is still available. If the creators of the class were careful, they have overridden `init` so it calls `initWithBar:` with a default argument.
- If you use runtime introspection or `class-dump` to find out the method list on class `A`, then you **can** indeed declare (perhaps in a category) and call `- [A initWithBar:]`.
- But if you don't want to do any of these (especially #2 since it's a hack), then why not just create a similar convenience method? Something like this:

---

```
@implementation B

+ (B *)beeWithBar:(NSString *)bar
{
    B *instance = [self aWithBar:bar];
    instance.someOtherProperty = 42;
    return instance;
}

@end
```

Note that again, this will only work if the developers took care and implemented `aWithBar:` using `[self initWithBar:]`. If the class name is hard-coded (as in your example), then you can't get an instance of `B` by calling the convenience method.

Comment: The instance is still class A. And message to B doesn't seem to work in your third solution. It says unrecognized selector.

Comment: @huggie See the last notice in the answer. The developers didn't pay attention and you have basically no other option.

Comment: Thanks gotcha. I guess I'll do encapsulation instead. Thanks.

Comment: The last notice do you mean [[self alloc] initWithBar:]? I tried it on Xcode 4.6 it will still says it is class A (by NSLogging [a_instance class]). Curiously I tried it on Xcode 5 with iOS 7 both cases return class B. There seems to be a change in runtime.